# How to use jquery to handle multiple json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am developing a website with front-end and back-end separated. I used jquery to send request and get the result as a json object:

```
{
  "item": [

  ],
  "shop": [

  ],
  "user": [
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "full_name": "Minh Duc",
      "email": "nguyenminhduc1803@gmail.com",
      "fb_link": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/SieuNhan183",
      "user_name": "Duc",
      "password": "37cd769165eef9ba6ac6b4a0fdb7ef36",
      "level": "0",
      "admin": "0",
      "dob": "1996-03-18",
      "location": "Ho Chi Minh",
      "user_image_url": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i am finding a way to get the data from the object user. How can i do it with javascript?

Comment: $jsonObject.user[0] would be the user object you want. Use . (dot) to access the object property you want

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the data (in example it's in `data`) use the dot notation to get the node with the user.

The user is an array, so use `[]` to access a single element, e.g. `[0]`

```js
var data = {
  "item": [

  ],
  "shop": [

  ],
  "user": [
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "full_name": "Minh Duc",
      "email": "nguyenminhduc1803@gmail.com",
      "fb_link": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/SieuNhan183",
      "user_name": "Duc",
      "password": "37cd769165eef9ba6ac6b4a0fdb7ef36",
      "level": "0",
      "admin": "0",
      "dob": "1996-03-18",
      "location": "Ho Chi Minh",
      "user_image_url": null
    }
  ]
}


console.log( data.user[0].user_id )
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @arcs answer, remember that in Javascript you can access members of an object using dot notation (`data.user[0].user_id`) or square brackets notation. This way:

```
data['user'][0]['user_id']
```

this is useful because you can have a 'class' array and then do things like:

```
['item', 'shop', 'user'].forEach((array) => processArray(data[array][0]));
```

then you can filter only some classes or do more advanced stuff

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use square brackets like this :

```
$jsonObject["user"][0]["user_id"]
```

but you can use the dot like this :

```
data.user[0].user_id
```

is the same thing.

If you want check if property exist you can do it :

```
if(typeof $jsonObject["user"] !== 'undefined'){
  //do domethings as typeof $jsonObject["user"][0]["user_id"] 
}
```

If you want get property dinamically you can do it :

```
const strId = "id";
const strName = "name";

//get user_id
let user_id = $jsonObject[user][0]["user_" + strId ];
//get user_name
let user_name = $jsonObject[user][0]["user_" + strName];
```

but there isn't very pretty.